# docker ps: how to show specific columns as output?

Tags: docker

docker ps: showing multiple-lines for each container makes it difficult to see.

How to select columns to display like sql?

```
docker ps -a ID,NAME,STATUS
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `--format`:

```
docker ps --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}\t{{.Status}}"
CONTAINER ID   NAMES     STATUS
```

Also please read the help section: `docker ps --help` which references:
https://docs.docker.com/go/formatting/

> **table**
>
> table specifies which fields you want to see its output.
>
> $ docker image list --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Repository}}\t{{.Tag}}\t{{.Size}}"

Comment: Works. but quite complicated.

Comment: Well, that's how its implemented. The good things is that this is available.. if it was not, you would have to use a more complicated way to accomplish the same

Comment: It also works for `docker compose`. Here's a version that includes NAME, SERVICE, CREATED and STATUS columns: `docker compose ps --format "table {{.Name}}\t{{.Service}}\t{{.RunningFor}}\t{{.Status}}"`